# How to pass data in single product page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api, redux-toolkit

How to pass data inside single product page ??

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart: CartReducer,
    product: ProductReducer,

  },
});
```

productSlice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { STATUS } from "./StatusSlice";

const ProductSlice = createSlice({
  name: "product", 
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    status: STATUS.IDLE,
  },

  reducers: {
    setProducts(state, action) {
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
    setStatus(state, action) {
      state.status = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setProducts, setStatus } = ProductSlice.actions;
export default ProductSlice.reducer;

export function fetchProducts() {
  return async function fetchProduct(dispatch) {
    dispatch(setStatus(STATUS.LOADING));
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products#");
      const data = await res.json();
      dispatch(setProducts(data));
      dispatch(setStatus(STATUS.IDLE));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(setStatus(STATUS.ERROR));
    }
  };
}
```

here is product page

```
const Products = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProducts());
  }, []);

  if (status === STATUS.LOADING) {
    return <h1>Loading......!!</h1>;
  }
  if (status === STATUS.ERROR) {
    return <h1>Something went wrong</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={style.wrapper}>
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} key={product.id}>
              // rest of the codes
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

i'm not able to understand how get data in single product page

```
const SingleProduct = () => {

  return (
   // details
  );
};
```

i had two option,

1. i can fetch api data in products page, single product page and wherever i want to or
2. i can fetch api data in one page (productSlice) and use everywhere that's why redux has been made.

Need Solution :

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the product id as part of the URL path:

```
{products.map((product) => {
  return (
    <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} key={product.id}>
      // rest of the codes
    </Link>
  );
})}
```

Assuming you have a router and a route for `path="/products/:productId"` rendering the `SingleProduct` component:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route path="/products/:productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
  ...
</Routes>
```

Then the `SingleProduct` component can use the `useParams` hook to access the `productId` route path parameter value and use this to filter the `products` array selected from the redux store.

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const SingleProduct = () => {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.product.data);
  const { productId } = useParams();

  const product = products.find(product => String(product.id) === productId);

  if (!product) {
    return "Sorry, no matching product found.";
  }

  return (
    // render product details
  );
};
```